# How to set variable by select?

Tags: mysql

In MSSQL， I can use:

```
select @desc_out=desc01
,      @flag_out=flag 
from   A01 
where  id=@id_in
```

to set variable.

But in MySQL, is it possible to set variable using `select`?

This is MSSQL code：

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A01](
    [id] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [desc01] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [flag] [varchar](1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

if (select OBJECT_ID('p_A01')) IS NOT NULL DROP proc p_A01;
CREATE proc p_A01 @id_in varchar(4),@desc_out varchar(20) output,@flag_out varchar(1) output
as
begin
  select @desc_out=desc01,@flag_out=flag  from A01 where id=@id_in
end;

declare @desc_out varchar(20);
declare @flag_out varchar(1);

EXEC p_A01 'A001',@desc_out output,@flag_out output;
select  @desc_out, @flag_out;
```

Please suggest me same using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select @desc_out:=desc01,@flag_out:=flag  from A01 where id=@id_in
```

ie for setting the variable in `select` in MYSQL you need to use `:=` instead of `=`

Also it would be better if you can `declare` your variables before using them in `select`.

Comment: thx, but how to set b or c output by use

select b:=cName,c:=cSex from students where cID='1';

Answer (score 0):

use `@name:=` pattern. ex:

```
SELECT @desc_out:=desc01 .....
```